# CocoaPods build failing due to unresolved identifier

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have a swift project that uses Obj-C cocoapods, but whenever I build, it failed due to unresolved identifiers for `setBackgroundImageForState` as well as `setImageForState`.

My Podfile contains:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.1'

pod 'AFNetworking'

pod 'AnimatedGIFImageSerialization'

pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'

pod 'JTSImageViewController'

pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

and I have run `pod install`.

My bridge file contains:

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking.h>
#import "TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.h"
#import "JTSImageViewController/JTSImageViewController.h"
#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>
```

and it is linked correctly in the project settings.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Well, did you check where the import fails?

Comment: @AlexBartiş I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. It isn't saying the import failed. I'm assuming the import never even happened in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wrote that wrong. I meant where the build fails. I see that that those are AFNetworking methods, so I imagine afnetworking either is not installed completely/correctly or maybe there is a problem with the build targets?

You can try this https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate plugin to uninstall all pods and do a cleanup, then retry to run pod install on your pods.

Comment: @Wiz Out of curiosity, how did you eventually solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal, `cd` to the directory where your `Podfile` resides:

```
] ls
...
Podfile
```

Remove former installation:

```
] rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock
```

Re-install:

```
] pod install

Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.6.0)
Installing AnimatedGIFImageSerialization (0.2.0)
Installing JSQMessagesViewController (7.1.0)
Installing JSQSystemSoundPlayer (2.0.1)
Installing JTSImageViewController (1.4)
Installing TTTAttributedLabel (1.13.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder (option-shift-command-K). You may also want to remove the derived data for good measures (Xcode > Window > Projects > Delete).